# Limit anonymous petitions in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a landing page when you can get budgets. I am using JS/HTML in Frontend and Django in Backend.
I would like to limit the petitions to anonymous users, because you do not have to be register to get the budgets.

I get the IP like this:

```
def visitor_ip_address(request):

   x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')

   if x_forwarded_for:
     ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
   else:
     ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
   return ip
```

The point is, I do not know if is the best way to get a IP from one session or the same laptop, for limit it. My goal is limit the petitions in incognito navigation as well, from the same laptop.

How is the best way to do it?
Thanks

Comment: This is too broad to answer here but Google "browser fingerprinting" for starters. IP addresses can be shared by multiple users/laptops/devices and are not reliable. Some mobile networks use a single IP address (CGNAT) for all customers.

Comment: Yes, is the problem. I am trying to find the way to limit anonymous users petitions. Limit IPs is the way that I have seen, but now is difficult to do it.
Is there some different way in Django?

Comment: Please read my comment again. There are ways (although not perfect) and they are called browser fingerprinting methods. See https://fingerprintjs.github.io/fingerprintjs/ for an example.

Comment: Ahh, ok, thanks. I did not understand well. I will search it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you concerned at "malicious" users clearing their cookies? Because if not, you could just use the Django session to store the number of petitions so far. Anonymous users have anonymous sessions, but a knowledgeable user will know how to become a different anonymous user.

You can still  rate-limit by not allowing a user to submit a petition until a time interval after his anonymous session was first created. Something like:

```
# initialize first-time visitor
if "first_usage" not in request.session:
    request.session['first_usage'] = datetime.datetime.now()

now = datetime.datetime.now()
delta = now - request.session['first_usage']
hours = delta.total_seconds() / 3600.0

# now you can refuse a petition if the user first visited the site 
# less than some number of hours ago. And you can store the dates of
# the last submitted petition into the session, to check that this
# anonymous user is not exceeding a more precise rate limit.
```

Comment: Yes, I knew about it. I can combine it with fingerprint for increment the segurity, thanks for your answer. However, the idea is control petitions in incognito window, as well.